# Transfer from Haneda to Narita with ski bags

Tags: luggage, japan, nrt, hnd

If I arrive in Haneda and take the bus shuttle to Narita, is there lots of room for luggage on the bus (as I will be travelling with 2 ski bags and one regular bag)?

Answer (score 5):

**Yes.** The Airport Limousine is a standard high "tourist" bus with tons of luggage space.  The official allowance is two large suitcases, but they allow surfboards (and hence, presumably, equally awkwardly sized ski gear) under 2m in length on a space-available basis, and in my experience the buses are rarely if ever full.

Source: http://www.limousinebus.co.jp/en/guide/baggage.html

Answer (score 2):

A the bus can't guarantee to be able to take your skis, I would advise that you take the train. There are direct trains from Haneda to Narita that cost half as much as the bus.

Comment: I would not like to wrestle with 2 ski bags and a suitcase on regular trains in Japan, especially since the only direct services between the two airports don't even have luggage racks.

Comment: I wouldn't imagine it would be too much of a problem, you'll be getting on at the beginning of the route and getting off at the end. The trains do have luggage racks above the seats which could easily accomodate skis (especially as you getting on at the beginning and they will likely be empty). When dealing with flights, I'd happily make the slight tradeoff of ease of getting on off of the the train for the huge boost in realiabiliy it offers.

Comment: I'm usually a train fanboy, but for the specific case of HND-NRT transfers, buses are faster, more frequent, and quite reliable since they avoid central Tokyo traffic.  In comparison, there are only a few direct trains per day, you usually need to transfer at least once, and the racks are not intended for luggage so a suitcase won't fit.  (Skis might though.)

Comment: Most of the infromation in that last comment is wrong. there are plenty of direct through trains during the day (1 or 2 an hour), buses DO go through central Tokyo and so can be subject to traffic delays and there is no trouble having a suitcase on the train.

Comment: @paulb I see they've indeed increased train frequency (yay!), but there are still no through trains at peak commuter hours (roughly 7-10 AM, 5-7 PM).  The Limousine buses take the Wangan Expwy through Odaiba and thus avoid central Tokyo, and the few times I took a suitcase on packed Keikyu commuter services the experience was unpleasant.  YMMV.